# Vertical scrollbar scrollTo jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I'm using the scrollto jquery plugin (http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-one-page-navigation-plugin).

It's a single-page website that scrolls horizontally. But there is also a page with larger content, so that page scrolls vertically. As you can see in this example: http://www.seegermattijs.be/!/ When you go from 'projecten' to 'seeger', the vertical scrollbar also slides, and this is not what I want (if you can't see the scrollbar, resize your browserscreen).

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Put the `overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: auto;` to the `wrapper`, not to the child elements.

Comment: That works but then each 'page' has a scrollbar. I don't know if there is a solution for that?

Comment: you can hide the content after crolling out the page. then scroll is not available to each pages.